# TFS Business Case

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to build a business case for moving from VSS to TFS and in particlar I'm looking for clarity on the costs and risks of NOT doing this.

What would your top 3-4 killer reasons that would save a company more than £10k?

Many thanks.

Comment: The big problem with VSS is that you need to run it off a network share so there's no server to centrally coordinate locking. So there's a risk of data loss / corruption. That said if you've survived with VSS all this time (!) I guess that's unlikely to happen to you. Once you're past that, though, TFS is more about features: CI, SharePoint, scalability. But there's other options out there too.

Comment: there is sourcegear have you not tried that?

Comment: There are so many many reasons for moving from VSS to... anything.  I use and love TFS.  And the migration story from VSS to TFS is lots better these days than it was when I migrated.  But even if you don't go with TFS you should leave VSS fairly soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What would your top 3-4 killer reasons that would save a company more than £10k?"

One of the best answers out there is [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9749156).  This whitepaper goes over, in detail, all of the advantages.

Here is an exert from the pdf file:

> **Performance, Reliability and Scalability**
>
> Backed by SQL Server 2008, Team
> Foundation Server benefits from the
> performance and scalability of an
> industry leading, enterprise class
> database server. For small teams that
> don’t need the power of a full-fledged
> SQL Server installation, installing on
> a client OS like Windows7 and using
> SQL Server Express provides the same
> powerful engine in a lightweight
> package. This provides one of the key
> benefits that VSS never had – you can
> start small and grow over time.
> Upgrading from SQL Server Express to
> the full version of SQL Server is as
> simple as a backup and restore. Other
> benefits of SQL Server include the
> ability to dynamically expand storage
> as needed, faster read/writes, and
> clustering as part of a fault tolerant
> solution.
>
> The tight integration of
> Team Foundation Server and Visual
> Studio provide users with a familiar
> and effective source controlled
> development environment. Typically
> Visual SourceSafe developers had to
> open the VSS user interface outside of
> Visual Studio to accomplish source
> control tasks. Because of the Team
> Foundation Server integration with
> Visual Studio, virtually every option
> regarding source code and work items
> can be accomplished directly through
> Visual Studio (some administrative
> features need to be accomplished
> through the full-featured command
> line).
>
> One issue that tends to effect
> VSS installations is the 4GB
> recommended limit. Teams which are
> close to this limit or have exceeded
> it tend to find corruption issues in
> their source code requiring repair.
> Restoring this data from a backup is
> frequently difficult because teams
> have to rely on system administrators
> to restore the file share. Here again,
> Team Foundation Server takes advantage
> of the power of SQL Server. SQL Server
> has built-in protection against data
> corruption but, if that occurs, it can
> be restored through a SQL Server
> backup. SQL Server allows for many
> different data protection schemes from
> incremental and full back ups to log
> shipping and mirroring which all
> provide reliable mechanisms for
> protecting your data.
>
> **Security**
>
> In VSS,
> security is limited to three settings
> – Admin, Read/Write and Read. Applying
> security settings at the file level
> was possible, but the experience was
> far from easy. The major drawback to
> this security was that it was an all
> or nothing type of security – if you
> could write to the file you could do
> anything you wanted with it. And
> because everything was stored on a
> file share, anyone with access to the
> file share could simply delete it all.
>
> While granular security of your source
> code may not be critical, Team
> Foundation Server does provide it.
> Along with being able to control
> security at the file level, teams can
> also support specific scenarios such
> as letting a developer check out a
> file but not check it in. This is
> handy in many situations such as peer
> reviews and outsourced development.
> And, since it is stored in SQL Server,
> losing all of your source code because
> of a delete will never happen again.